# How to use ruby open-uri with https proxy

Tags: ruby, open-uri

When I try to use http proxy everything is ok, but when I try https proxy I get this error:

```
p = open('http://google.com', proxy: "https://190.72.158.80:8080")

>> RuntimeError: Non-HTTP proxy URI: https://190.72.158.80:8080
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the proxy URL with http instead of https :

```
p = open('http://google.com', proxy: "http://190.72.158.80:8080")
```

Comment: This explains the open uri proxy options: 
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/OpenURI/OpenRead.html